# Best practice to use else{} or use return?

Tags: php, methods, return

Hey I have been programming for a few years now and just recently I was wondering what is best to do in a method that is always going to return something:

```
if($age < 18) {
    return 'Under 18';
}
else {
    return 'Adult';
}
```

Or is it better to use:

```
if($age < 18) {
    return 'Under 18';
}
return 'Adult';
```

In the latter if they are under 18 the program will return 'Under 18' and terminate the rest of the function so is there any need for that else{} in the first example? Thanks.

Comment: Obviously there is no difference _in this case_, you know that yourself. So what is your _real_ question?

Comment: Use the latter, if you need an opinion on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to return early. Nested if elses make conditionals even worse!

**Simplified (no elses) Example**

```
//nested (without return)
if ($a == 1) {
    if ($a == 2) {
        if ($a > 2) {

        }
    }
}

//return early
if ($a == 1) {
    return 1;
}

if ($a == 2) {
    return 2;
}

if ($a > 3) {
    return $a;
}
```

**Explanation**

The reason returning early is desired is because (in my opinion) of how the brain processes nested ifs. You will notice yourself when reading a nested if structure you always seem to keep track of the previous if conditions. If you flatten it out like i did it's easier for your brain to process (weird considering it does the same thing).

Returning early in general is better because you don't have to read ALL the code up until the return statement - it's also faster to execute but how much faster depends on the code itself.

**Further Reading**

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from

Comment: Further reading = exact duplicate in programmers.stackexchange.com lol

Comment: `The reason returning early is desired is because of how the brain processes nested ifs. ` Evidence? I don't have a problem with either.

Comment: Then your have more brain power :p I hate large nested if else conditions with all the comments etc - just a big mess i feel as you also have to keep track of where you are in the hierarchy and as it moves across the screen to the right and horizontal scroll bars appear >< You really like that kind of code!?

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos There's duplicates all over the place - but the one i picked seemed to have loads of upvotes so i went with that one. The fact it's a duplicate is irrelivant because it's much more in depth and aged than this one so hence, further reading ><

Comment: No, then I refactor it. It's just that you seem to voice an opinion but dress it up as a fact, also you're exaggerating from the OP's original code.

Comment: "It's just that you seem to voice an opinion but dress it up as a fact" - just edited my answer to correct that.

Comment: ;) Keep in mind to @tag people when you're not replying to the OP.

Comment: @phant0m You again!!!...

Comment: I was just letting you know that I saw your reply. And no, I haven't started stalking you, I didn't even notice you were the same person previously. But I did notice you were new and thought I could point out a thing or two to that I have learned from SO over the times ;) (Yeah, `$key => $val` syntax would be better of course instead of `array_key()`)

Comment: @phant0m ;) Keep in mind to tag people when you're not replying to the OP. :P lol

Comment: In this case, you *are* the OP ;) (of the post the comments belong to, that is of course)

Comment: @phant0m Oh sh*t, my bad lmao. Forgot i posted this answer ><

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a right or wrong way with both of these examples. Both work - Personal coding style is the main factor really. I myself would use the latter style, as that way the function/method will always have something to return even if the if statement is borked (in more complex situations).

Answer (score 0):

Some say it's matter of personal taste, but I think that it's best to have one entry point and **one exit point** in the method/function as this usually helps debugging and controlling function flow (so you are not "surprised" by sudden `return` in middle of the code. So ny code would rather be:

```
$result = 'Adult';
if($age < 18) {
    $result = 'Under 18';
}

return $result;
```

aside from example code being not really fortunate as it should be rather written:

```
return ($age < 18) ? 'Under 18' : 'Adult';
```

Comment: `Some say it's matter of personal taste, but I think` no "but" ;)

Comment: @phant0m You mean I wrote this wrong in English? Could be (I'm not native) - mind pointing to any exact English rule I violated or something that I could read more about that?

Comment: "Silent" downvoter mind speaking up to discuss his vote?

Comment: The `but` can imply that you don't think it's a matter of taste, the `I think` part mitigates that to some extent though. As such, the construction just doesn't make too much sense for me, because `but` is usually used to contradict or contrast the preceding statement ;) Also, I don't think `as it should be rather written` is appropriate, since it's a matter of style ;) - That's also the reason I "voted to close" on this question.

Comment: I find the second option you wrote (and I read too late) much much more useful for this case. I have my own answer, but this is a great one, it deserves +1.

Answer (score 0):

As for me - the first one is more readable. But there is no much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Both are programatically the same (second one maybe an operation more but, in computational terms, completely the same). Therefore, the only changes would be aesthetic. I would suggest the second option if your code is not going to change. But, if it's going to grow, you might be interested in the first option.

If the code is not going to grow, I'd personally set as this:

```
return ($age < 18) ? 'Under 18' : 'Adult';
```

Or, depending on your requests, even this could be interesting:

```
return ($age >= 18);
```

It takes unnecessary code out making it less bloated while keeping functionality and readability. If you can keep it simple and perfectly understandable, don't complicate yourself. I find tempted to quote Einstein here (;